# Navigate to New View Controller after Animation is Completed in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I have (2) goals:

1. Example #1: Navigate from the original View Controller to a new SecondViewController after the following animation is completed in Swift 3.0 (i.e. the User does not have to press any button and the App simply moves to the SecondViewController after the animation is completed)
2. Example #2: Navigate from the original View Controller to a new SecondViewController after a time delay of 5 seconds in Swift 3.0 (i.e. the User does not have to press any button and the App simply moves to the SecondViewController after a timer reaches 5 seconds - no animation involved in the second example, just a timer)

Here is my code for Example #1:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var imagesName = ["Image_1","Image_2","Image_3","Image_4","Image_5","Image_6","Image_7","Image_8","Image_9","Image_10","Image_11","Image_12","Image_13","Image_14","Image_15"]

    var images = [UIImage]()

    for i in 0..<imagesName.count{

        images.append(UIImage(named: imagesName[i])!)
    }

    imageView.animationImages = images
    imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
    imageView.startAnimating()

// Perhaps here is where we can fire the code to programatically move to a new View Controller after the animation is completed

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Here is my Xcode setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`.

**EDITED**

Set Storyboard ID to SecondViewController.

[image]

Example #1:

```
...
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1 // <-- here
imageView.startAnimating()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + imageView.animationDuration) {
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
    self.show(secondViewController, sender: nil)
}
```

Example #2:

```
...
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1 // <-- here
imageView.startAnimating()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
    self.show(secondViewController, sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kosuke Ogawa - one follow up question, when the original View Controller moves to the SecondViewController I receive a black screen with no content.  Do you know what may be wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Does your SecondViewController has Xib/Storyboard?

Comment: If yes, use `let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")`

Comment: Thanks @Kosuke Ogawa - please find an updated screenshot of the Xcode setup to help clarify

Comment: Thanks @Kosuke Ogawa - all good, we needed to add "!" to the line: self.show(secondViewController!, sender: nil).  One last question, when I uncomment the imageView.animationDuration = 1.0, the animation plays almost twice and then the story board moves to the second ViewController.  I have tried different values for the duration but none seem to work clean.  Is there a way to set this so that the moment the animation has finished playing the story board moves to the second View Controller?  many thanks

Comment: Why did you uncomment the imageView.animationDuration? The default value of this property is 0.0. So you shouldn't uncomment this property.

Comment: See also official document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621058-animationduration

Comment: Thanks @Kosuke Ogawa - with this line uncommitted the animation does not run through the entire animation before the View Controller triggers your code to move to the SecondViewController

Comment: Thanks @Kosuke Ogawa - instead of uncommenting the imageView.animationDuration line, would we add the following line in its place: var animationDuration: TimeInterval {0.00}

Comment: Your first issue is resolved? If you have other question, ask new question.

Comment: Thanks @Kosuke Ogawa - if I may the first issue is still outstanding.  In Example #1 the goal was to navigate from the original View Controller to a new SecondViewController after an animation is completed in Swift 3.0.  As I mentioned this does not occur, only part of the animation plays (it does not complete) prior to the storyboard moving from the original View Controller to the new SecondViewController.

Comment: It may be caused by an infinite loop of animation. Try `imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1` to prevent it.

Comment: I just posted another similar question if you would like to view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306561/random-selection-of-animation-in-swift-3-0

Comment: @ Kosuke Ogawa - would you mind taking one last look, the animation still plays once and then repeats the first few images before we move to the SecondViewController.  Where would you insert the imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1 line?  I have tried a number of places in the code and none seems to work.  Many thanks :)

Comment: You should insert the `imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1` line before `imageView.startAnimating()`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @ Kosuke Ogawa for circling back - when I place the line before imageView.startAnimating() it doesn't display any images

Comment: @ Kosuke Ogawa - would you mind taking one last look, the animation still plays once and then repeats the first few images before we move to the SecondViewController. Where would you insert the imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1 line? I have tried a number of places in the code and none seems to work. Many thanks :)

Comment: I placed the line before `imageView.startAnimating()`. (I edited my answer) It works fine for me.

Comment: @ Kosuke Ogawa - if I comment out your line in the above code: `imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1` the animation plays fine it just loops through 1.5 to 2.0 times

Comment: @ Kosuke Ogawa - I have tried putting the line before the startAnimating line but then no animation appears (it is just a blank screen). Here is my code: `imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1 imageView.animationImages = images imageView.animationDuration = 0.5 imageView.startAnimating() DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + imageView.animationDuration) { let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") self.show(secondViewController!, sender: nil) }`

Comment: How about `imageView.animationDuration = 0.5 imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1 imageView.animationImages = images imageView.startAnimating() DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + imageView.animationDuration) { let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") self.show(secondViewController!, sender: nil) }` ?

Comment: @ Kosuke Ogawa - it still does not display any images

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can I see your sample project? -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/oxNfk.jpg

Comment: Hi @ Kosuke Ogawa - if you add a splash screen with an image just before the new View Controller that plays the animation, it seems to cause the error.  If you leave the splash screen blank then the animation runs exactly as you suggested, not sure why

Comment: Hi @ Kosuke Ogawa - I have posted another question you may want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434894/ios-add-custom-annotation-and-then-pass-variables-to-a-new-view-controller-via-a

Comment: Hi @Kosuke Ogawa - thank you for your answer.  Here is a related question if you would like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717839/add-modal-popup-to-map-annotation-swift-3-0